# Can someone help me please? it is about width of the table

Tags: tables, longtable, width

My table is too wide and too long to fit one page.
i want to seperate it to 2 pages.
i used longtable package to seperate it two pages
bu i cant fix the wideness.

her is my table code, (it look a little mess sorry about that if you copy and paste to your latex you see it better)

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}

\usepackage{tabularx}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}

 \caption{aaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aaaa aa}\\

 \hline
  \multirow{2}{*}{Nuclei} & \multirow{2}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering Data\\Range}} &           \multirow{2}{*}{$\sigma$}  & \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{CT} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{BSFG} &    \multicolumn{3}{c|}{L}\\
  \cline{4-12}
 &   &   &  $T$ & $\Delta$ &  $\chi^2$   &  $a$  &  $\Delta$  & $\chi^2$  & $a_L$   &     $\Delta$  &  $\chi^2$ \\
 \hline
 \multirow{9}{*}{\textsuperscript{76}As} & \multirow{3}{*}{ \parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering      2-82\\RIPL-3\\disc.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 1.33 & -5.43 & 23.65 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
 \cline{3-12}
 &   & GC & - & - & - & 5.60 & 4.43 & 23.33 & 3.02 & 2.33 & 23.05 \\
  \cline{3-12}
   & & RB & - & - & - & 5.84 & 4.91 & 23.34 & 3.36 & 2.97 & 23.11 \\
  \cline{2-12}
   & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 2-82\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} &      Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.95 & -3.43 & 31.31 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
   & & GC & - & - & - & 9.73 & 1.92 & 58.40 & 5.43 & 0.66 & 79.69 \\
   \cline{3-12}
   & & RB & - & - & - & 10.70 & 1.81 & 74.46 & 3.75 & 2.42 & 113.09 \\
   \cline{2-12}
  & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 6-27\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20}       & 0.95 & -3.51 & 1.74 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & GC & - & - & - & 9.90 & 1.97 & 1.48 & 5.80 & 0.67 & 1.34 \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & RB & - & - & - & 10.85 & 1.84 & 1.41 & 7.04 & 0.64 & 1.23 \\
  \hline
  \multirow{9}{*}{\textsuperscript{198}Au} & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 3-91\\disc.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.81 & -2.69 & 13.61 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
  &   & GC & - & - & - & 9.01 & 2.43 & 13.21 & 4.81 & 1.12 & 12.74 \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & RB & - & - & - & 9.55 & 2.82 & 13.24 & 5.50 & 1.63 & 12.87 \\
  \cline{2-12}
  & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 13-91\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20}       & 0.60 & -1.65 & 22.35 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & GC & - & - & - & 15.93 & 0.78 & 60.16 & 9.70 & -0.085 & 99.79 \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & RB & - & - & - & 18.47 & 0.70 & 84.45 & 12.38 & -0.11 & 156.17 \\
  \cline{2-12}
  & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 3-91\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20}       & 0.60 & -1.62 & 4.37 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & GC & - & - & - & 15.68 & 0.96 & 3.69 & 9.50 & 0.15 & 3.11 \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & RB & - & - & - & 18.08 & 0.93 & 3.43 & 12.05 & 0.19 & 2.66 \\
  \hline
  \multirow{9}{*}{\textsuperscript{138}Ba} & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 4-50\\RIPL-3\\disc.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 1.28 & -1.34 & 2.97 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
  &   & GC & - & - & - & 5.68 & 0.98 & 3.29 & 2.87 & -0.84 & 3.39 \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & RB & - & - & - & 6.06 & 1.67 & 3.29 & 3.35 & -0.09 & 3.37 \\
  \cline{2-12}
  & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 4-50\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20}       & 0.73 & 0.77 & 1.65 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & GC & - & - & - & 5.33 & 0.90 & 25.6 & 3.34 & -1.29 & 28.11 \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & RB & - & - & - & 6.33 & 1.40 & 29.93 & 3.41 & -0.09 & 30.21 \\
  \cline{2-12}
  & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 8-21\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20}       & 0.73 & 0.70 & 0.52 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & GC & - & - & - & 11.21 & -1.22 & 0.62 & 6.33 & -2.25 & 0.67 \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & RB & - & - & - & 13.22 & -1.29 & 0.72 & 8.44 & -2.19 & 1.04 \\
  \hline
  \multirow{9}{*}{\textsuperscript{60}Co} & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 7-65\\disc.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 1.03 & -1.93 & 1.74 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
  &   & GC & - & - & - & 5.68 & 0.98 & 3.29 & 3.24 & -0.02 & 1.46 \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & RB & - & - & - & 6.05 & 1.66 & 3.28 & 3.57 & 0.43 & 1.46 \\
  \cline{2-12}
  & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 10-65\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20}       & 1.17 & -2.54 & 2.31 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & GC & - & - & - & 6.95 & 1.26 & 1.91 & 3.94 & -0.46 & 4.23 \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & RB & - & - & - & 7.58 & 1.23 & 2.66 & 4.60 & -0.32 & 7.43 \\
  \cline{2-12}
  & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 7-15\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20}       & 1.13 & -2.13 & 0.11 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & GC & - & - & - & 7.03 & 1.17 & 0.11 & 3.95 & -0.41 & 0.11 \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & RB & - & - & - & 7.62 & 1.22 & 0.11 & 4.59 & -0.18 & 0.14 \\
  \hline
  \multirow{9}{*}{\textsuperscript{166}Ho} & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering       2-154\\disc.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.53 & -1.60 & 76.29 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
  &   & GC & - & - & - & 13.84 & 1.37 & 69.13 & 7.41 & 0.54 & 63.03 \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & RB & - & - & - & 14.37 & 1.54 & 69.34 & 8.18 & 0.78 & 64.23 \\
  \cline{2-12}
  & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 11-154\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} &       Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 0.60 & -2.07 & 42.44 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & GC & - & - & - & 9.52 & 2.65 & 84.46 & 5.20 & 1.39 & 84.82 \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & RB & - & - & - & 9.75 & 3.13 & 86.47 & 5.73 & 1.89 & 88.53 \\
  \cline{2-12}
  & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 2-16\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20}      & 0.56 & -1.49 & 0.79 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & GC & - & - & - & 17.76 & 0.78 & 0.48 & 10.96 & 0.08 & 0.43 \\
  \cline{3-12}
  & & RB & - & - & - & 19.42 & 0.79 & 0.45 & 12.09 & 0.14 & 0.48 \\
  \hline
  \pagebreak
  \caption{xxxx}\\
  \hline
    \multirow{9}{*}{\textsuperscript{139}La} & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 4-     33\\RIPL-3\\disc.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20} & 2.02 & -6.46 & 2.74 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
     \cline{3-12}
     &   & GC & - & - & - & 3.59 & 5.54 & 2.73 & 1.90 & 2.36 & 2.72 \\
    \cline{3-12}
    & & RB & - & - & - & 3.88 & 6.93 & 2.73 & 2.25 & 3.92 & 2.72 \\
    \cline{2-12}
    & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 4-33\\RIPL-3\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20}      & 0.78 & -0.76 & 7.40 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
   \cline{3-12}
   & & GC & - & - & - & 4.27 & 4.11 & 30.97 & 2.08 & 1.88 & 31 \\
  \cline{3-12}
    & & RB & - & - & - & 4.03 & 6.50 & 31.13 & 2.30 & 3.74 & 31.14 \\
     \cline{2-12}
     & \multirow{3}{*}{\parbox[t]{2cm}{\centering 4-21\\Koning\\disc.+res.}} & Eq.\eqref{eq:20}       & 0.79 & -0.88 & 0.94 & - & - & - & - & - & - \\
    \cline{3-12}
    & & GC & - & - & - & 11.63 & -0.01 & 0.91 & 7.07 & -1.08 & 1.23 \\
   \cline{3-12}
   & & RB & - & - & - & 12.94 & 0.02 & 0.97 & 8.42 & -0.95 & 1.51 \\
   \hline

   \end{longtable}

   \end{document}
```

Comment: Please do not double-post.

Comment: i posted first one wrong. thats why i duplicate it.

Comment: You can edit questions, there is no need to open a new question (or you can delete the old one)

Comment: Please edit the question to be a complete document that allows people to see the table. A fragment that may not be processed is not as helpful. (it may just need `...`  replacing with `\begin{document}` but it is for you to check that the example accurately reflects your problem